# can I reprot my own fake name of OS I am using with Mozilla FireFox?

Tags: firefox, operating-systems, about-config

My bank with IB stops supporting Windows 8.
I'm using it along with Mozilla FF.
How can I send my own version of OS (say Windows 10) so that I can continue using Internet Banking ?

Comment: Does https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/uaswitcher/ solve your issue?

Comment: @DavidPostill Good. I've installed it. But where can I switch to another OS version ? It's pretty new to me! By the same token doesn't this only change `user-agent` FF but also OS which is what I need ??

Comment: The user agent is what some websites use to detect the OS.

Comment: As David has said, the user-agent request header would more than likely be what's identifying your OS. With your add-on to FF, and making sure the change is made, you could try a private browsing window to ensure a new header is sent.

Answer (score 1):

When an organisation stops supporting an old OS, it's often because something in that OS is missing that is required for their service to continue working correctly.

In this case, that is going to be exacerbated by Windows 8 reaching End of Life 10 Jan 2023. After that, any loophole found by hackers will be open season, without fear of any patches to close the hole. Your bank is not keen on that happening to you - in case you sue for something that is quite clearly not their fault - you were warned.

This is not fixed by mis-reporting the browser, but by updating the OS.

Comment: I really do not wish to update my OS with the understanding that it may work incorrectly from time to time. I just want to firmly circumvent the blocking via a false OS name reported by Firefox. Is that possible ? The only thing my Win 8 is not OK for the bank may be a security flaw in it.

Comment: Your bank do not want you to be vulnerable to security flaws on an OS that will go completely unsupported in a month. Any OS that hits that point becomes an immediate target for hackers, who know whatever they manage to break will never be fixed. Your choice to continue using Win 8 is one you really need to reconsider. It is now 7 years past its 'sell by date'.

Comment: @Tetsujin probably in this case it's because Windows 8.1 EOL is January 10, 2023.

Comment: @DrZoo - precisely. As I mentioned, 'in a month' [or less;)

Comment: Try a new OS without need to install it, e.g. a live Ubuntu USB, https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ , if you're unable to move to Windows 10. If that works with your bank, you can keep using it from USB, or install it.